# Zend framework query with innerjoin and AS

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I try to Get the follow query into a valid zf query but I getting keep errors. I hope
someone can help me with this one.

```
SELECT c1.id as c1id, c1.cat, c2.id,c2.sub_cat
FROM `categories`as c1
inner join categories as c2 on c2.cat = c1.cat
where c1.seo = 'tech'
```

Regards,

Nicky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried converting it into a Zend_Db_Select query?

```
$sel = $db->select();
$sel->from(array('c1' => 'categories'), array(
    'c1id' => 'c1.id', 
    'c1.cat',
    'c2.id',
    'c2.sub_cat'
));
$sel->join(array('c2' => 'categories'), 'c2.cat = c1.cat', array());
$sel->where('c1.seo = ?', 'tech');
```

Comment: I get the follow error "Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c1.c1id' in 'field list'" When I execute the raw query in phpmyadmin, it works perfect.

Comment: It seems to work when I change c1id to just id, isn't that strange? I cant understand the reason

Comment: My mistake, I've mixed up the order for that column. It should be 'alias' => 'column_name'! Updated the answer.